# PageSpeed Insights: poor both mobile and desktop

Tags: mobile, desktop, pagespeed

I am not a programmer nor developer and although I followed the links on Google to remove the problems it showed, I do not understand a thing. Therefore I would like to ask you to tell me in some comprehensible words what I should do to rectify the optimisations so that the speed of my pages is as it should be.

Comment: Can you ask more specific questions? What have your tried? What, specifically, did you not understand? If you're not a developer, I have to ask, with the greatest respect, why you're asking on a developer forum? ;)

Comment: Hello, no, I am not a developer. I asked immediately the GitHub and they recommended you...

Comment: OK, but I think you'll need to provide more detail -- what, exactly, is the problem? Where does it appear? If the problem affects web pages, where are they hosted? How were the created? What development technologies are involved?

Comment: Hello, this is the problem: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=moreyouthfulskin.com

Comment: You have a URL loop. /en redirects to /en/home, and /en/home redirects to /en. Is this the problem you are concerned about, or does the sight display properly for some people?

Comment: Thank you for your information and the hint. Actually, I am concerned by everything found by Google. Or if the problem with redirects would be removed, all other errors would disappear? Do I need to contact a developer or can I do it by myself?

Comment: I suspect that, based only only looking at the site, there is no way to tell whether the problem lies in the configuration of the server, or the authoring of the site. Sorry :/

Comment: Thank you for all your replies and endeavour to help. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

> Reduce server response time

Your web server is TOO SLOW!
Getting a better ISP/Host is the easiest way to significantly speed up your page.  This will speed things up about 10X.  All those 600-900ms response times in the waterfall should be one tenth the time.

**For example** your style.css takes only `7 ms` to download the file, but the server waited `632 ms` to send the first byte. This is almost a 100X unnecessary delay.

```
URL: https://moreyouthfulskin.com/wp-content/themes/wellness-pro/style.css?ver=1.0.0
Loaded By: https://moreyouthfulskin.com/en/home/:59
Host: moreyouthfulskin.com
Request Start: 5.951 s
Time to First Byte: 632 ms
Content Download: 7 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 7.9 KB
Uncompressed Size: 36.9 KB
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.2 KB
```

**This above data is from this link:** [Web Page Performance Test for https://moreyouthfulskin.com/en/home/](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/171101_AC_8d6191e2ea2d56ddbbbf72551735efa8/)

> Leverage browser caching

The 1 day cache is not a big deal, it is a small issue. It is more of a warning.  It is a web server setting. It is not worth much effort when you have so many other serious issues.

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

The CSS after the JS is big. This is usually caused by WP plug-ins.  Only use plug-ins that do not degrade performance.  Check your page speed be and after installing any plug-in. Then think about whether it is worth it.

> Remove or at least speed up the redirects.

Your redirects are costing you because your web server is too slow. Get a new ISP.  The two redirects took over 5 seconds.  This means there is an unnecessary 5 second delay before the page even begins to load the first byte of the home page.

> Optimize images, Minify JavaScript, and Minify CSS

At the bottom of Google Pagespeed results there is a link to Optimized images, Minified JavaScript, and Minified CSS.  Download them, then upload them to the proper directory/folder on your server. This one is easy.  If you cannot do this then you are in this way over your head.

**END OF UPDATE**

---

Your biggest issue is you have CSS and fonts being loaded after the JavaScript.  This is costing you about 5 seconds load time.

Also your page load had two redirects using 2 seconds.

Your server needs to be configured to use a longer max-age cache .
Curently your cache is 14400 seconds.  `cache-control: public, max-age=14400`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I had a look at this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching but not being a developer do not understand a thing. Is there a plugin that would solve the issue please? Thank you for letting me know, Milada

Comment: No plug-in can fix this.  It's a web server setting.  Forget abut this one for now.  See my UPDATE.

Comment: The part of my post that says UPDATE to End of Update

Comment: Thank you, I have downloaded the Optimized images, Minified JavaScript, and Minified CSS from Google. I should now unzip the zipped file including the above items and delete css, image, js folders in my ftp and replace them with css, image, js from Google? Is that correct? As in my ftp there is no css folder, I delete style and style-front files and replace them with css folder files from Google? I am asking you this, because, there is no explanation on the Google download page. Thank you again.

Comment: There was another file, Manifest, but not saying which suffix. Probably json, which I found in: root /www - should I delete the existing one and replace it with the one from Google, too?

Comment: No, but if you did, it does not matter.  Host your site on a different server, this one is too slow.

Comment: You mean a different hosting? What speed should a hosting have, not to be "too slow"?